ExtJs7.4: app is locking up in tablet, but works fine on desktop, is this a memory leak issue?
I have created a fairly complex ExtJs app (using version 7.4 modern toolkit) that has some "modules" that use a transaction model, that is, a single instance of the model can be loaded at a time, and navigation controls enable loading a specific transaction id.
This app runs fine on a desktop, but we recently tried running it on an Android tablet, and after loading a few transactions, the app locks up. Sometimes it will start working again after a long delay, as though the system was overloaded.
I have been able to reproduce the problem on my development desktop by simply loading the page in tablet/responsive mode, so it appears that ExtJs handles things differently if it detects a non-desktop device.
Has anyone run into this kind of overload problem? Any pointers for where I should be troubleshooting?
Thanks!
Update:
Here is my base model, which includes a schema:
Ext.define('App.model.Base', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: [
        'Ext.data.identifier.Negative',
    ],

    identifier: 'negative',

    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int', unique: true},
    ],

    schema: {
        // Setting the models namespace to produce proper association getter names.
        // https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/modern/Ext.data.schema.Schema.html
        namespace: 'App.model',

        proxy: {
            type: 'restApp',
            url: 'rest/{entityName}',
        },
    },
});

Update December 31:
Here is a link to a video demonstrating the problem I'm experiencing.

Do you use a development or production build?

Good point to consider, but the issue appears in both development and production builds.

I just take a wild guess: You added a scheme to the model.
Most likely you have a racing condition in you application. This does not matter on desktop, but might on other devices.
Ensure to require the scheme in your model.
In your case add somthing like this to the model:
requires: ['MyApp.model.SchemeName'],

To figure out, what might happen, do a test build (sencha app build testing).
You might have required all app-files (requires: ['MyApp.*']), but on top of that you need to require the SchemeName in that model:
The main problem is, that sometimes your Model is loaded before your Scheme (might be alphabetically so some Models do not need it and some do) => and that way the constructor runs before the Scheme is known.
Docs
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/modern/Ext.data.schema.Schema.html
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Base', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     
     schema: {
         namespace: 'MyApp.model'
     }
 });

This defines that the proxy calls from baseUrl/base, because MyApp.model is cut from the filename. And has a couple of other advantages.

Thanks for your input. A racing condition does sound plausible, but I'm not sure where to start looking.
I don't totally understand how schemas work, but I do have one on the base model, as shown in my updated post.

Oh, I thought you meant schema. I'm not familiar with the term "scheme" in the context of ExtJs, and am not understanding what adding requires: ['MyApp.model.SchemeName'], to the model is supposed to do. Can you point me to some documentation?

See updated answer

If you do not use a base model, which uses a schema, nor you use the schema config anywhere, your problem might have a different source
